# Elasticsearch: When serving a read request, why not try to find the document in the memtable first to achieve real-time query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch official document [Near real-time search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/near-real-time.html), it says that

> In Elasticsearch, this process of writing and opening a new segment is called a refresh. A refresh makes all operations performed on an index since the last refresh available for search.

> By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second, ... This is why we say that Elasticsearch has near real-time search: *document changes are not visible to search immediately, but will become visible within this timeframe.*

I feel a little confused: when serving a read request, why not try to find the document in memtable first, then in the on-disk segment, if so, we do not need to wait the refresh, which makes the real time query possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really good question, but to understand it why Elasticsearch doesn't serve a search request from in-memory documents, we will have to little deep and understand why segments are created in first place and why they are immutable.

As you might be aware that segments are the actual physical files that stores the data of search index, and segments are immutable and **this immutability provides a lot of benefits such as**

1. Segments can be cached.
2. Segments can be used in multi-threaded Environments without worrying about the state being change.

Now as segments are cached and can be used in multi-threaded Environment, it's much easier to use the file system cache to provide the faster search, of-course that means sometime, you will not have a newer copy of data but thats a trade-off than iterating through the memtable which is still being modified and still can show the old version of the document(so still you have a near real time data), and can't be cached as its not immutable so every search thread will end up searching on a dataset which is always in motion and if you apply the locking  on `memtable` while searching, it would reduce the indexing speed.

**Btw, this is design from Lucene and Elasticsearch uses that as a library so it's not really Elasticsearch which controls that.**

**Bottomline, even if you search on memtable without locking and blocking updates while searching, you can't show the real time data and this would considerably slow both indexing and search speed.**

Hope this helps.